# Recoding variables in SAS

Tags: sas

I’m very new in learning SAS.
How I can combine three variables into a new variable using “OR” function in SAS?

For example:
I have three variables as “A”, “B”, and “C”. I want to have a fourth variable as “ A” or “B”, or “C”.

I tried creating new variables, it didn’t work for me.

Comment: Please show what you've tried, what you have and what you're trying to get as output as well so we help you out. As posted, this post does not meet StackOverflow guidelines and will likely get closed. [ask]

Comment: Can you post an example of your expected output and the code you've tried? It's really hard to figure out what you're trying to do. Do you literally want a variable that says "A or B or C"?

Comment: Are A, B and C the names of the variables to check?  Or are they values to be looked for? if the later what is the name of the variable than could contain the values of "A" or "B"?  What is the name of the new variable you want to create?

Answer (score 0):

What interface are you using to write and submit SAS code?

Numeric values in SAS have an inferred logical meaning.

- FALSE, 0 or missing
- TRUE, not-0 and not-missing.

Use the `OR` operator.

```
newvar = A or B or C ;
```

If the values in A, B, and C are bitwise important, use the `BOR()` function.

```
newvar = BOR (BOR (A, B), C) ;
```